# Why does the text not appear in the div that I place it in?

Tags: html, css

Im making a pricing page for my website but as I'm making my website responsive, (only when the page is less than 110 pixels wide),

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

#pricing {
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #E5EDFB;
  margin-top: none;
}

h1 {
  color: #0E0A24;
  padding-left: 8.75%;
  padding-top: 5vh;
  font-size: 300%;
}

h2 {
  color: #0E0A24;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 175%;
}

p {
  color: #0E0A24;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

span {
  font-size: 120%;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.smallTile {
  background-color: white;
  width: 23vw;
  height: 65%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.largeTile {
  background-color: white;
  width: 28vw;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#photo {
  margin-left: 8.75%;
  position: relative;
  top: 27%;
  transform: translateY(-27%);
  float: left;
}

#video {
  margin-right: 8.75%;
  position: relative;
  top: 27%;
  transform: translateY(-27%);
  float: right;
}

#combo {
  margin-right: 8.75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 60%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
}

hr {
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-bottom: 6%;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #0E0A24;
  border: none;
  height: 0.1px;
  ;
}

.topHR {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  margin-bottom: 4vh;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  ;
}

#comboHeader {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 200%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .smallTile {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 86vw;
    height: 95vh;
  }
  .largeTile {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 86vw;
  }
  #photo {}
  #video {
    margin-top: 100vh;
  }
  #combo {
    margin-top: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=p ricing>
  <h1>Our Pricing:</h1>

  <div class="smallTile" id="photo">
    <h2>Photography<br>Plan</h2>
    <hr class="topHR">
    <p><span>0 - 10 Pictures</span><br>$100</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>10 - 20 Pictures</span><br>$175</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>20+ Pictures</span><br>$250</p>
  </div>

  <div class="smallTile" id="video">
    <h2>Videography<br>Plan</h2>
    <hr class="topHR">
    <p><span>0 - 5 Videos</span><br>$100</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>5 - 10 Videos</span><br>$150</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>Edited Video</span><br>Additional $50</p>
  </div>

  <div class="largeTile" id="combo">
    <h2 id="comboHeader">Combo<br>Plan</h2>
    <hr class="topHR">
    <p><span>Combined price of both plans</span><br>$50 Reduced</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

I noticed that the combo package text is at the bottom of the page instead of in the div where I placed it. Additionally, is it possible to change the order of the divs so that the combo package is last on the responsive site only? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have a look at CSS flex and grid - they may help you with the layout.

Comment: Sorry, Im still a bit of a beginner, would you mind explaining a bit better?

Comment: He is talking about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). You can build your layout using this technology. It is pretty easy.

Comment: My suggestion is that you drop using things like float and top/left positioning and transforms to get things into place and instead look at CSS grid. The link given by @AliMustafa is where I’d start.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you did not specify the float value for the combo div. Add float to the combo styles as such:

```
#combo{
    margin-right: 8.75%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
    float: left;
}
```